# Typescript: How to derive one type from another using a map within the same interface

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following type definitions

```
const enum INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR {
    EQUAL = "EQUAL",
    LIKE = "LIKE",
    CONTAINS = "CONTAINS",
    CONTAINS_LIKE = "CONTAINS_LIKE",
    NULL = "NULL",
    NOT_NULL = "NOT_NULL",
}
type SearchFieldTypeMap = {
    [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.EQUAL]: string;
    [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.LIKE]: string;
    [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.NULL]: [];
    [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.NOT_NULL]: [];
    [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.CONTAINS]: Array<string>;
    [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.CONTAINS_LIKE]: Array<string>;
};
type SearchCondition<O extends INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR> = {
    fieldName: SEARCH_FIELD
    operator: O
    values: SearchFieldTypeMap[O]
  }
type SearchFieldCondition = {
    field: SearchCondition<keyof SearchFieldTypeMap>;
};
```

Idea being that the value of the search condition is enforced based on the type of operator that is provided.
However when I use this, it allows any of the `SearchFieldTypeMap` types to be used for any of the operator types. It doesn't seem to map through.

e.g

```
const mySearchQuery: SearchFieldCondition = {
  field: {
    fieldName: "FilterX",
    operator: INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.NULL,
    values: ['Hello']
  }
};
```

I would have expected to throw an error since the expected value type for `INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.NULL` should be be an empty tuple `[]`.
However it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGHV3.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here is a sandbox to test https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-mapped-types-error-dh53z?file=/src/index.ts
Just seems to allow any of the mapped types in the SearchFieldTypeMap regardless of the operator type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close

```js
const enum INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR {
  EQUAL = "EQUAL",
  LIKE = "LIKE",
  CONTAINS = "CONTAINS",
  CONTAINS_LIKE = "CONTAINS_LIKE",
  NULL = "NULL",
  NOT_NULL = "NOT_NULL"
}
type SearchFieldTypeMap = {
  [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.EQUAL]: string;
  [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.LIKE]: string;
  [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.NULL]: [];
  [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.NOT_NULL]: [];
  [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.CONTAINS]: Array<string>;
  [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.CONTAINS_LIKE]: Array<string>;
};
type SearchCondition<O extends INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR> = {
  fieldName: string;
  operator: O;
  values: SearchFieldTypeMap[O];

};
/**
 * Fortunatelly, it does not work like that
 * You still should explicitly pass your generic
 */
type SearchFieldCondition<T extends INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR> = {
  field: SearchCondition<T>;
};

const mySearchQuery: SearchFieldCondition<INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.NULL> = {
  field: {
    fieldName: "FilterX",
    operator: INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.NULL,
    values: ["Arrghhhhhh"] // here is an expected error
  }
};
console.log(mySearchQuery);
```

**Second approach**

```js
const enum INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR {
  EQUAL = "EQUAL",
  LIKE = "LIKE",
  CONTAINS = "CONTAINS",
  CONTAINS_LIKE = "CONTAINS_LIKE",
  NULL = "NULL",
  NOT_NULL = "NOT_NULL"
}
type SearchFieldTypeMap = {
  [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.EQUAL]: string;
  [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.LIKE]: string;
  [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.NULL]: [];
  [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.NOT_NULL]: [];
  [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.CONTAINS]: Array<string>;
  [INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.CONTAINS_LIKE]: Array<string>;
};

/**
 * This util makes one big union type
 */
type SearchCondition = {
  [P in keyof SearchFieldTypeMap]: {
    fieldName: string;
    operator: P;
    values: SearchFieldTypeMap[P];
  }
}[keyof SearchFieldTypeMap]

type SearchFieldCondition = {
  field: SearchCondition;
};

const mySearchQuery: SearchFieldCondition = {
  field: { // error is here
    fieldName: "FilterX",
    operator: INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.NULL,
    values: ["Arrghhhhhh"]
  }
};

const mySearchQuery2: SearchFieldCondition = {
  field: { // no error
    fieldName: "FilterX",
    operator: INV_SEARCH_OPERATOR.NULL,
    values: [] // no error
  }
};
console.log(mySearchQuery);
```

Comment: Hmm, thank you. But that's not really what I was after. The idea was that it was picked up from the value pass to the operator field, so I wouldn't explicitly have to tell it.

Comment: Ooh, now the second approach is exactly what I was after, did not know you could do that.
You beautiful human being, I think you just saved Christmas. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for kind words, Will!